# Android: error java.lang.illegalargumentexception: width and height must be > 0, although the method invocation happens in onResume()

Tags: java, android, webview

I want to save an image from a WebView into the gallery. I'm trying first to get a Bitmap from the WebView but my getBitmapFromWebView(WebView webView) method throws above error. That means that measuredWidth and measuredHeight are 0 although I'm invoking the method from onResume() which was the most often proposed fix of the issue in similar threads (I've read similar questions but didn't find a solution). Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong and how to fix it? I have to make a screenshot of the webview and save it into the gallery. That is my code:
MainActivity.java:

```
      package com.example.fractal;

      import android.content.Intent;
      import android.graphics.Bitmap;
      import android.graphics.Canvas;
      import android.graphics.Paint;
      import android.graphics.Picture;
      import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
      import android.net.Uri;
      import android.os.Environment;
      import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.view.View;
      import android.webkit.WebView;
      import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
      import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;

      import java.io.File;
      import java.io.FileOutputStream;
      import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
      import java.util.Date;

      public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       WebView myBrowser=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);
       myBrowser.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
       //myBrowser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
       myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      // myBrowser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
      // myBrowser.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
      // myBrowser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
      // myBrowser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());


       myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/fractal.html");
     }

     public void saveButton(View view) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
     }

     //YES button from SecondActivity
     public static Bitmap getBitmapFromWebView(WebView webView) {
      try {
        int widthMeasureSpec =    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        int heightMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

        //Measure WebView's content
        webView.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        webView.layout(0, 0, webView.getMeasuredWidth(), webView.getMeasuredHeight());

        //Build drawing cache and store its size
        webView.buildDrawingCache();

        int measuredWidth = webView.getMeasuredWidth();
        int measuredHeight = webView.getMeasuredHeight();

        //Creates the bitmap and draw WebView's content on in
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(measuredWidth, measuredHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Paint paint = new Paint();

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, bitmap.getHeight(), paint);

        webView.draw(canvas);
        webView.destroyDrawingCache();

        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception | OutOfMemoryError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
private void save(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
    myDir.mkdirs();

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String fname = "fractal_"+ timeStamp +".jpg";

    File file = new File(myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists()) file.delete ();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        //add to gallery
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(file)));

        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{file.toString()}, new String[]{file.getName()}, null);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

/* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void saveTempBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (isExternalStorageWritable()) {
        save(bitmap);

    }else{
        //prompt the user or do something
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    WebView wb=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);
    Bitmap mybitmap=getBitmapFromWebView(wb);
    saveTempBitmap(mybitmap);
 }
}
```

Image rendered in the WebView: fractal.html

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=0;"  />
     <title>My HTML</title>
     </head>
     <body>
        <script>
         (function() {
           // Create Canvas
            var myCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            myCanvas.width=260;
            myCanvas.height=250;
            document.body.appendChild(myCanvas);
            var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");

            // Start drawing
            function checkIfBelongsToMandelbrotSet(x, y) {
            // TO DO
           var realComponentOfResult = x;
           var imaginaryComponentOfResult = y;
           var maxIterations = 100;
           for(var i = 0; i < maxIterations; i++) {
           var tempRealComponent = realComponentOfResult *   realComponentOfResult
                             - imaginaryComponentOfResult * imaginaryComponentOfResult
                             + x;
     var tempImaginaryComponent = 2 * realComponentOfResult * imaginaryComponentOfResult
                             + y;
     realComponentOfResult = tempRealComponent;
     imaginaryComponentOfResult = tempImaginaryComponent;

        // Return a number as a percentage
       if(realComponentOfResult * imaginaryComponentOfResult > 5) 
        return (i/maxIterations * 100);
       }
       return 0;   // Return zero if in set  
    }

    var magnificationFactor = 85;
    var panX = 2;
    var panY = 1.5;
   for(var x=0; x < myCanvas.width; x++) {
     for(var y=0; y < myCanvas.height; y++) {
        var belongsToSet = 
           checkIfBelongsToMandelbrotSet(x/magnificationFactor - panX, 
                                      y/magnificationFactor - panY);
           if(belongsToSet == 0) {
            ctx.fillStyle = "violet";
            ctx.fillRect(x,y, 1,1); // Draw a black pixel
         } else {
            ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(310, 100%, ' + belongsToSet + '%)';
            ctx.fillRect(x,y, 1,1); // Draw a colorful pixel
        }  
       } 
      }
    })();
      </script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Layout file: activity_main.xml :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">


<WebView
    android:id="@+id/mybrowser"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="89dp"


    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mybrowser"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="140dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="380dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="140dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="140dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:onClick="saveButton"
    android:text="@string/save_image" />


 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So the `makeMeasureSpec` method calls return a value <=0. Why? And what does that have to do with onResume?

Comment: In similar questions (about the same error) I've read that probably the measurements are 0 because the picture has not been drawn yet but calling the method within onResume() should guarantee that the activity is loaded and the views are already drawn and presented to the user.   About makeMeasureSpec I don' t know, I just used this method [link](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=android.webkit.WebView&method=measure)  and applied it on my WebView.

Comment: My app has 2 activities. I perform the saving of the image on return from my second activity. Rendering the fractal in the WebView and switching between the activities with buttons is working fine, but the saving operation is causing this issue that I can't resolve on my own. I'm new to Android development, any help is welcome.